# How to divide an image into 4 different tones? Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, rgba

I am trying to make an image split into the hues: red, green, blue and gray (grayscale).

So far I have only managed to make the entire image change to a single tone, but my goal is to divide it into 4 quadrants and each one has a different tone.

I attach the code where I can show the image with a single tone:

```
from PIL import Image

    img = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
    layer = Image.new('RGB', img.size, "blue")
    salida = Image.blend(img, layer, 0.5)
    salida.show()
```

Could anyone advise me? I don't know how to divide the image with the tones I require, I have already tried modifying the above code but have not been successful.

Comment: I'm unclear as to whether you want to split by hue (i.e. colour) or by geometry (i.e. quadrants). Could you provide representative input and corresponding output images please? Thanks.

Comment: Copied without attribution from [¿Cómo dividir una imagen en 4 tonos diferentes?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/408023)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that what you are doing is just adding a blue overlay instead of splitting into hues.

I guess, this is what you really want:

```
from PIL import Image

FILENAME = 'imagen.jpg'

# Split into layers
img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGB')
R, G, B = img.split()
Z = Image.new('L', img.size, 'black')
RZZ = Image.merge('RGB', (R, Z, Z))
ZGZ = Image.merge('RGB', (Z, G, Z))
ZZB = Image.merge('RGB', (Z, Z, B))
gray = img.convert('L')

# Create an image with quadrants
res = Image.new('RGB', (2*img.size[0], 2*img.size[1]))
res.paste(RZZ, (0,0))
res.paste(ZGZ, (img.size[0], 0))
res.paste(ZZB, (0, img.size[1]))
res.paste(gray, (img.size[0], img.size[1]))
res.thumbnail(img.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)        # optional: resize to the original size
res.show()

res.save('res.png')
```

Resulting image:

[image: Image layers shown in four quadrants]